# For the existing object add a newly created object without modifying the other objects, here its loosig other properties

Tags: angularjs

`branchAccess.pendingList[i]` object loosing other properties like it had.

`branchAccess.pendingList[i].testMyAccessStatus` its `undefined` after assigning newly added. can we use `angular.copy` or `angular.clone` to keep the object with its existing properties and also add a newly created object `accessStatusDetails`?

This is my code:

```
this.selectAll = function(branchAccess) {

        //checking if undefined
            var accessStatusDetailsAdd = {
                     accessStatusDetails : { accessStatus : "A" }
                }

            if(branchAccess.pendingList[i].accessStatusDetails == undefined){
                branchAccess.pendingList[i] = accessStatusDetailsAdd;
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check **angular.extend()** function

```
var object1 = {
  "color": "yellow",
}

var object2 = {
  "animal": "horse",
}

var mergedObject = angular.extend(object1, object2);

// mergedObject = {
//    "color": "yellow",
//    "animal": "horse"
// }
```

Comment: AweSome! Working superb, I need to add one more step ;Little Explanation - I have a selectAll 'checkbox' which would add above object to all the list of rows which are radio Buttons and selects the radio button in each row; Now, I need to  uncheck "SelectAll" checkBox and unselect all radio buttons; Above method adds by adding branchAccess.pendingList[i] = accessStatusDetailsAdd;                     Now to unselect radio button I need branchAccess.pendingList[i].accessStatusDetails.accessStatus = false wondering how to do on click of CANCEL button (Uncheck check Box and Unselect radio buttons)